# How to get rid of React-Bootstrap Dropdown Button box-shadow?

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get rid of the box shadow or second border on the bootstrap dropdown button when I click on it.

I couldn't find which class makes this change.

[image: Screenshot of bootstrap dropdown button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons get appropriate ":focus" classes on focus, which add box shadows:

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 25%);
}
```

To deactivate this behaviour, set "box-shadow" css property to "none". There is a utility bootstrap class called "shadow-none" which does the same: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/shadows/

Answer (score 0):

Igor's efforts got me on the right track, but I want to add some details.

The bootstrap shadow-none works for normal buttons, but i think the React-Bootstrap library's DropdownButton component overrides it. So I ended up making a new custom style in order to inject the !important over-ride on it.

...like so:

```
.no-focus-dropdown-button {
  :focus {
    box-shadow: none !important; // must use !important to override
  }
}
```

And then use it in the component's class like so:

```
<DropdownButton
title="Dropdown Button"
className="no-focus-dropdown-button"
>
  {DropdownItems()} // with your items here
</DropdownButton>
```

*note, I've heard it might not be such a good idea to strong-arm the focus like this, since the visual cue is helpful for some people.